# How to insert a linebreak as the data of a cell using Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I use Apache POI 3.16 to create an Excel file. I want to set the data inside a particular cell to have a linebreak :

```
rowConsommationEtRealisation.createCell(0).setCellValue("Consommation (crédits)\r\nRéalisation (produits)");
```

When I open the file then the cell value does not have linebreak ! So how to create linebreak ?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Try this: [here](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NewLinesInCells)

```
Row row = sheet.createRow(2);
Cell cell = row.createCell(2);
cell.setCellValue("Use \n with word wrap on to create a new line");

//to enable newlines you need set a cell styles with wrap=true
CellStyle cs = wb.createCellStyle();
cs.setWrapText(true);
cell.setCellStyle(cs);
```

Answer (score 10):

It has the line break already, but the cell did not show it. You need to set the cell style to have wrap text property.

Example:

```java
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;


class ExcelLineBreakWrapText {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

  CellStyle wrapStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
  wrapStyle.setWrapText(true);

  Row row = sheet.createRow(0);

  Cell cell = row.createCell(0); 
  cell.setCellStyle(wrapStyle);
  cell.setCellValue("Consommation (crédits)\r\nRéalisation (produits)");

  sheet.autoSizeColumn(0);

  workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("ExcelLineBreakWrapText.xlsx"));
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```