# Row content height is only adjusted after clicking on a cell NPOI

Tags: c#, npoi

I am using NPOI to export some data to excel, inside a cell I am inserting 3 items with 2 lines breaks so I am adjusting the row height accordingly:

```
var row = sheet.CreateRow(1);
row.Height = 900;

var questionString = "Question 1" + Environment.NewLine + "Question 2" + Environment.NewLine;
```

When exporting the excel the row height is adjusted, however the contents of the cell are clustered unless I double click on the cell.

Result when exporting:

[image: Before]

Result after double clicking on the cells:

[image: After]

Comment: How are you writing to the cell? Perhaps you need `Environment.NewLine` to separate content.

Comment: I am adding Environment.NewLine, I have updated the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert a linebreak as the data of a cell using Apache POI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48040638/how-to-insert-a-linebreak-as-the-data-of-a-cell-using-apache-poi)